# Are Amazon SNS and Spring Integration same?

Tags: spring-integration, amazon-sns

I came across "Amazon SNS" it is also a message sending service having complete structure and components like in "Spring integration"(topic, endpoints, pub/sub, synchronous). But haven't found out are they similar things so one can choose as an alternative solution or are they working together to build messaging system?

I know Spring integration is a Spring framework component and work with only Spring Framework and seems like Amazon SNS can be used with Spring Framework or simple Servlet/JSP technology to achieve messaging.

**Please shed light on my knowledge. Thanks**

Comment: Unlike Spring Integration, Amazon SNS doesn't implement EIP: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/. You need to start from the theory

Comment: So it means it is an alternative solution?

Comment: It's not relevant. Amazon SNS is just one of the messaging protocols. Spring Integration provides implementation for many of them, including this SNS: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws. You just don't compare apples with apples. That's why I'm closing your question and suggest to read more.

Comment: alright, Thanks Artem
but please don't close question, news answers give me new ways of thinking

Comment: Yeah... I'm afraid this is not how things work on SO. Everybody is going to come and close your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You are restricted in what you can ask here on SO